# How to perform multiple finds for regex containing group with multiple lines?

Tags: java, regex

- **Platform:** Java
- **Current pattern:**`(/[^:" ()]+\..[^: "()]+).*(\d.*?):(\d.*)?.*?((?:warning|error|note): .+)`
- **Problem:** for group 4, it only matches to the end of line. If I add `DOTALL` it finds only one set of groups with the description of the last find.

**Input for which I want to find a match - the one that goes into `pattern.compile(String)`:**

```
Build failed: Command failed with exit code 1.
stderr: /sample/path/to/SampleFile.java:1: error: [PackageLocation] Expected package /sample/path/to/ to be declared in a directory ending with /sample/path/to, instead found /sample/path/To
package sample.path.to;
                   ^
    (see http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/PackageLocation)
/sample/path/to/SampleFile2.java:-1: note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

/sample/path/to/SampleFile2.java:-1:6 note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

**Expected output:**

### Find 0

- **group 1:** /sample/path/to/SampleFile.java
- **group 2:** 1
- **group 3:** null
- **group 4:** error: [PackageLocation] Expected package /sample/path/to/ to be declared in a directory ending with /sample/path/to, instead found /sample/path/To;
                 ^
  (see http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/PackageLocation)

### Find 1

- **group 1:** /sample/path/to/SampleFile2.java
- **group 2:** 1
- **group 3:** null
- **group 4:** note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

### Find 2

- **group 1:** /sample/path/to/SampleFile2.java
- **group 2:** 1
- **group 3:** 6
- **group 4:** note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: Is the caret actually in the input or is that to show us what is not being caught?

Comment: Caret (\n) is actually in the input

Comment: So the caret is not actually there, it's just a newline character?

Comment: guys, the error is the string that I want to find a match for with `pattern.matcher(String)`

Comment: The runtime error you're showing is telling you that you have a misnamed package.  It has nothing to do with your regex or other inputs.

Comment: @ctwheels Yes it is just a new line character

Comment: @avgvstvs the OP is trying to parse the input (error/notes) for relevant information

Comment: @ctwheels my bad.  I'll leave this embarrassing mistake for others to read.

Comment: @avgvstvs no worries, I was slightly confused at first too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

Making some slight modifications to your regex, you can use this.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/fLRXXx/1)

```
(/[^:" ()]+\..[^: "()]+):-?(\d.*?):(\d.*)?.*?((?:warning|error|note): (?:(?![\r\n]{2})[\s\S])+)
                        ^^^                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

### Explanation

Instead of counting on the end of the line to determine the end of the match, I decided to use a double newline character (since this seems to be a common delimiter between the 3 lines). I'll focus on explaining the parts I added/modified.

1. I changed `.*` to `:-?`

   - While this may be a small change, it could potentially help you to not catch incorrect parts of the string in the future.
2. `(?:(?![\r\n]{2})[\s\S])+` Match the following one or more times ([tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat/37343088#37343088))

   - `(?![\r\n]{2})` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not exactly two newline characters
   - `[\s\S]` Match any character (including newline characters)

Comment: Definitely got the idea! Thank you very much

Comment: @HumbleStudent I added an explanation above.